# Rails has_many conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

```
    c = "(f.profile_id = #{self.id} OR f.friend_id = #{self.id})"
    c += AND + "(CASE WHEN f.profile_id=#{self.id} THEN f.friend_id ELSE f.profile_id END = p.id)"
    c += AND + "(CASE WHEN f.profile_id=#{self.id} THEN f.profile_rejected ELSE f.friend_rejected END = 1)"
    c += AND + "(p.banned = 0)"
```

I need this to be used in a has_many relationship like this:

```
    has_many :removed_friends, :conditions => ???
```

how do i set there the self.id?, or how do i pass there the id?
Then i want to use the will_paginate plugin:

```
    @profile.removed_friends.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

```
 class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :removed_friends, :class_name => 'Profile', :through => :friendships, :conditions => 
        "(friendships.profile_id = #{self.id} OR friendships.friend_id = #{self.id})"
        "AND (CASE WHEN friendships.profile_id=#{self.id} THEN friendships.profile_rejected ELSE friendships.friend_rejected END = 1)" + 
        "AND (p.banned = 0)"
  end


class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :removed_friend, :class_name => 'Profile', :foreign_key => "(CASE WHEN friendships.profile_id = #{self.id} THEN friend_id ELSE profile_id END)"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes to enclose the condition:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :removed_friends, :class_name => 'Profile', :through => :friendships, 
                             :conditions => '
    ( friendships.profile_id = #{self.id} OR 
      friendships.friend_id = #{self.id}
    ) AND
    (CASE WHEN friendships.profile_id=#{self.id} 
          THEN friendships.profile_rejected 
          ELSE friendships.friend_rejected 
     END = 1
    ) AND 
    (p.banned = 0)'
end
```

Comment: You have to use single quotes for this to work. I use this all the time.

Comment: Does that open you up to SQL injection attacks?  Seeing #{self.id} in there without parameter binding is concerning.

Comment: Note, this trick is deprecated in rails 3.05 and beyond.  You can accomplish the same thing with a proc or finder_sql

Comment: @JohnNaegle SQL injection in this case is unlikely as the code is substituting model attributes rather than user input. Off-course there is always a possibility that somehow a hacker managed to store spurious SQL in the id field(unlikely). I use this approach ONLY for `id` field.

Comment: Using it for only the ID field makes sense, I wanted to bring it up for other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to break this down into a series of named scopes that can be applied in stages instead of all at once. As an example, extract the banned part:

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :banned, lambda { |*banned| {
    :conditions => { :banned => banned.empty? ? 1 : (banned.first ? 1 : 0) }
  }}
end

@profile.friends.removed.banned(false).paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)
```

Using heavy-duty conditions in relationships is bound to cause trouble. If possible, try denormalizing the table, creating derivative columns that have "easy" versions of the data, or other things to make querying it easier.

Comment: is not the banned that is the problem. I will show you what im trying to do. I will edit my previous question..

Answer (score 0):

You really have two relationships here.  You have:

- A rejected friendship from the `profile_id` side
- A rejected friendship from the `friend_id` side

I don't know why both sides can reject a friendship, and maybe you need to look at your model for a little bit here (which side is requesting it?  Would it be better to consider that the requestor CANCELLED the request instead of saying it was rejected from the `profile` side?)

At any rate, I would model this as the two separate relationships that they are:

```
class Profile
  has_many :rejected_friendships, :conditions => 'friendships.profile_rejected = 1'
  has_many :canceled_friendships, :foreign_key => 'friend_id', :conditions => 'friendships.friend_rejected = 1'

  named_scope :banned, lambda do |*banned| 
      { :conditions => {:banned => banned.empty? ? 1 : (banned.first ? 1 : 0) } }
  end

  has_many :rejected_friends, :class_name => 'Profile', :through => :rejected_friendships
  has_many :canceled_friends, :class_name => 'Profile', :through => :canceled_friendships

  def removed_friends
    (self.rejected_friends.banned(false).all + self.canceled_friends.banned(false).all).uniq
  end
end
```

This is somewhat undesirable because removed_friends is not a relationship anymore so you can't do things like `Profile.removed_friends.find(:all, :conditions => {:name => "bleh"})` anymore, but this is a pretty complicated case.  That condition is quite complex.

Comment: in my db is like this: profile_id, is the one that makes the request, friend_id, is the one that recives the friend request, then there is a profile_rejected that is initially false, but if the profile_id reject the friendship will be set to true. then is a friend_rejected that is false. then is an accepted col that is false, and after the friend_id accept the friendship will be true.

the union ... + ... is really bad because i cant make request with sort, limit and offset to work good.

thanks anyway for your time, soon i will explain you better what did i mean. i come back really soon...