# How to make a Rails 4 ActiveRecord model with has_many that joins on a custom WHERE clause with an OR condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a database structure I am working with, where a `Node` relates to one of two possible fields in the `Interviewees` (either `clientnode_id` OR `caregivernode_id`):

```
tbl_nodes
+----+-----------+
| id | node_Name |
+----+-----------+
|  5 | some name |
+----+-----------+

tbl_interviewees
+----+---------------+------------------+
| id | clientnode_id | caregivernode_id |
+----+---------------+------------------+
|  1 |             5 |             NULL |
+----+---------------+------------------+
```

I am simply trying to define a `has_many` in the Node model where matches from either field are included.  The equivalent SQL would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_nodes LEFT JOIN tbl_interviewees ON (tbl_nodes.id=tbl_interviewees.clientnode_id OR tbl_nodes.id=tbl_interviewees.caregivernode_id)
```

I have currently attempted the advice on the following links to no avail (most use deprecated syntax):

[Rails 3: Use of lambda with scopes in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500221/rails-3-use-of-lambda-with-scopes-in-model)

[Rails has_many with dynamic conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462203/rails-has-many-with-dynamic-conditions/20412163#20412163)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference
[Rails has_many conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547207/rails-has-many-conditions)

Probably just something fiddly with the syntax, so any help would be appreciated.  I know this is wrong but this is my most recent attempt:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name_prefix = :tbl_
  has_many :interviewees, -> { where("clientnode_id=? OR caregivernode_id=?", self.id, self.id) }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nitin Thanks!  I was able to tweak your idea to get the behavior I wanted as follows:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  # replaces using a "has_many :interviewees" since it is joined off 2 different fields
  def interviewees
    Interviewee.by_node(self.id)
  end
end

class Interviewee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # called by Node model to get Interviewee association
  scope :by_node, ->(node_id) { where("clientnode_id=? OR caregivernode_id=?", node_id, node_id) }

  # replaces "belongs_to :node" since it is joined off 2 different  fields
  def node
    Node.where("id = ? OR id = ?", self.clientnode_id, self.caregivernode_id)
  end
end
```

I feel like doing it this way helps keep the encapsulation a little better, since Node shouldn't have to know the specific fields that Interviewees has.

This allows me to use the same .node and .interviewees method names and keep convention.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@nodes = Node.joins(:interviewees).where("interviewees.clientnode_id=:node_id OR interviewees.caregivernode_id=:node_id", node_id: <your id>)
```

By `scope`, write scope with parameter in the `model`

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interviewees
  scope :interviews_by_node, ->(node_id) { joins(:interviewees).where("interviewees.clientnode_id=:node_id OR interviewees.caregivernode_id=:node_id", node_id: node_id)
end
```

Call the `scope` in the `controller` action

```
class NodesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @nodes = Node.interviews_by_node(5)  
  end

end
```

I hope this would be helpful.